# Proof that the column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm writing a set of notes for a project on the four fundamental subspaces, and wanted to include a proof that the four spaces are subspaces of the standard spaces. This is my attempt at showing that the column space $C(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Did I miss any steps? Did get it wrong?

Suppose $\vec{c}, \ \vec{d} \in C(A)$, that is there exists vectors $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$, such that $A{\vec{y}=\vec{c}}$ and $\vec{z}=A\vec{d}$, where $\vec{y},\ \vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^m$
\begin{align*}
    \vec{c}+\vec{d} &= \vec{c} + \vec{d} &  & \\
    &= (A\vec{y}) + (A\vec{z}) & &{(substitution)} \\
    &= A(\vec{y}+ \vec{z}) & &(distributive \ property)
\end{align*}
Since $\vec{c} + \vec{d}=A(\vec{y}+\vec{z})$ we have shown closure under vector addition.

Now, suppose $\vec{b}\in C(A)$, that is, there exists a vector $\vec{x}$ such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$. Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
\begin{align*}
c\cdot \vec{b} &= c\cdot \vec{b} & &\\
&= c\cdot (A\vec{x}) & &(substitution)\\
&=A(c\vec{x}) & &(associative \ property)
\end{align*}
Since $c\vec{b}=A(c\vec{x})$, we have shown closure under scalar multiplication. We have the definition of a subspace, thus $C(A)\in \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: That is correct, except for your concluding statement "$C(A)\in \Bbb R^m$". That claims $C(A)$ is a **single vector** in $\Bbb R^m$, which is nonsense. $C(A)$ is a *set* of vectors in $\Bbb R^m$. And that is something you knew from the start. The conclusion of your argument is "$C(A)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$". Sorry, but there is no widely-recognized symbolic shortcut for that statement.

Comment: thank you so much!