# can col(a) and ker(a) establish a subspace?

Tags: matrices

col(A) establishes a 0 vector.  Not only a trivial solution

Closed under vector addition: col(A) establishes linear independence  . there are real vectors that span a real vector space

Closed under scalar multiplication.  Ker(a) establishes that an equation in Ax = b.  There are scalings that = 0, and then other scalings which will not equal 0.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. If you're asking whether $\text{col}(A)$ and $\ker(A)$ are subspaces, the answer is yes. If you're asking whether your justification of this fact is a correct, complete, and sufficient argument, the answer is no

Comment: how would I approach making this complete?

Comment: For instance, [here is a complete proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4407199/81360) that the column space is a subspace

Comment: why isn't establishing linearly independence in a matrix sufficient to proving it is closed under vector addition?  What is a counter example?

Comment: Well first of all, it's not at all clear what you mean by the sentence "col(A) establishes linear independence", so it would help if you could expand on that a bit